# Class can't access its own protected member variable using reflection from different package

Tags: java, reflection

I have  three classes: one base class `A` and two classes `B` and `C` that both extend `A`. `A` and `B` are in the same package and `C` is in a different package.

Both, `B` and `C` have a protected member variable. `A` has a method (lets call it `reflect`) that uses reflection and a string input to accesses a field with this name of a subclass via the `this` pointer.

Calling `reflect` from a `B` object is fine, but calling it from a `C` object results in an IllegalAccessException. I can not understand this exception, because this means that `C` has no access rights to access its own member variable. Why doesn't java allow this reflection?

Here is a MWE to clarify what I mean:

In `parent/A.java`:

```
package Parent;
public abstract class A {
    public Object reflect(String parameter) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException{
        Class cl = getClass();
        return cl.getDeclaredField(parameter).get(this);
    }
}
```

In `parent/B.java`:

```
package Parent;
public class B extends A{
    protected Integer b;
    public B(Integer b){
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

In `parent/child/C.java`:

```
package Parent.Child;
import Parent.A;
public class C extends A{
    protected Integer c;
    public C(Integer c){
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

and a small main:

```
import Parent.A;
import Parent.B;
import Parent.Child.C;
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B j1 = new B(10);
        C j2 = new C(20);
        try{
            Integer b_copy = (Integer)j1.reflect("b");
            System.out.println(b_copy); // prints "10"

            Integer c_copy = (Integer)j2.reflect("c"); // throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class Parent.A can not access a member of class Parent.Child.C with modifiers "protected"
            System.out.println(c_copy);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reflection allows you to bypass the access protection mechanism but you must explicitly instruct it to do so:

```java
package Parent;
public abstract class A {
    public Object reflect(String parameter) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException{
        Class cl = getClass();
        java.lang.reflect.Field f = cl.getDeclaredField(parameter);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        return f.get(this);
    }
}
```

In particular, you may be having the issue with `C` because you're actually accessing `C`'s protected variable from `A` since that's where you're performing the reflective call. You'd get the same access violation if you tried accessing `C`'s field directly from `A.reflect()`.

Comment: Thank you! But why is there a problem in first place? Why is `C` not allowed to access its own protected field?

Comment: The method that is accessing the protected field is defined in `A`. If you overrode the method in `C` with the exact same body in `A`, it would work because you would be accessing the protected method in `C`. If you try doing `((C) this).c;` in `A.reflect()`, you'll see that you get "The field C.c is not visible".

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

The exception is quite clear:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class Parent.A can not access a member of class Child.C with modifiers "protected"
```

The method is running under the namespace (=package) of class A.

Comment: Thank you! It was not clear to me that the method is not treated as a method from `C`.

Answer (score 1):

The `protected` access modifier implies package-visibility.

Notice that `A` is not a subclass of `B` or `C`, therefore the visibility of member variables for subclasses plays no role here.

However, since `B` is in the same package as `A`, and the member `b` is marked as `protected`, it is *also* package-visible, and therefore can be accessed from `A`.

For `C`, this is not the case, because `A` is neither a subclass of `C`, nor is `C` in the same package as `A`.